# React Hook "useDispatch" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

What i'm doing is creating an authentication system with react hooks. However, when I declare and call a constant using a react component it returns the error below. What is the right place to declare a constant and / or a function?

Error: ***React Hook "useDispatch" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function***

```
function handleSubmit({email, password}) {
  dispatch(signInRequest(email, password));
}

const dispatch = useDispatch();



class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        //Other code here
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't call react hooks outside functional component or in class component.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

```
const Login = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  function handleSubmit({email, password}) {
      dispatch(signInRequest(email, password));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        //Other code here
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using a class component and you are trying to use hook which will never wrong. Hooks should be called inside the functional component like:

```
const Login = () => {
 const dispatch = useDispatch();

function handleSubmit({email, password}) {
  dispatch(signInRequest(email, password));
}

    return (
      <>
        //Other code here
      </>
    );
  
}

export default Login;
```